# Remove pinterest button from all images except the main article

Tags: joomla, pinterest

I want to add a pinterest button to joomla articles, and I achieved it by adding the code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//assets.pinterest.com/js/pinit.js" data-pin-hover="true"></script>
```

But this code adds the button to all images in the page. How can I add it only to the main article image?

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest writing a small/simple [Content Plugin](http://docs.joomla.org/Creating_a_Plugin_for_Joomla) (see the developer tutorial link).  The Joomla SE site has a [question/answer](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/3961/add-a-class-to-all-images-in-article-dynamically/3962#3962) that discusses customizing images for articles - it may be a good starting point for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can put a pin it button next to an image with this:

http://networkconnected.co.uk/all-extensions/pin-it-any-image

Comment: Link only answers tend to get closed, you may want to add relevant details from that link in your answer.